# VSCode, Change Namespace of Report TYpes and Reports

Tags: vs-code, custom-report-type

My company makes an AppExchange App and we are changing the namespace for some customers. In VS Code I have been successful with Flows, and Classes.  I am now having trouble with Report Types.  I am receiving the error:

```
Base object cannot be changed after the report type is saved for the first time
```

In VS Code I am simply deleting the old namespace and replacing with new:

```
OldNameSpace__ObjectName__FileName__c. ->. NewNameSpace__ObjectName__FileName__c
```

Thank you

Comment: When does this error occur? Pushing to a Scratch Org? Deploying to a Publishing Org? While creating a Package Version? How are you changing the namespace, exactly? Creating a new package? The more information we have, the better we can assist you with this problem.

Comment: It sounds like your VS Code is deploying on save into an org. I really hope that's not your packaging org, as you may be risking significant damage. You can't change the namespace; what you're doing is building a completely new package.